# Django Admin built in auth views do not go away

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, web

I am creating a Python Django app and working through authentication. I want to create my own styled html templates and forms to use with the built in flows. I have the following url configuration in my `accounts/` app:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from .views import CustomRegisterView, ProfileView, CustomLoginView
from .forms import CustomLoginForm, CustomPasswordResetForm

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('register/', CustomRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(authentication_form=CustomLoginForm), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(form_class=CustomPasswordResetForm), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

I have sub-classed the `login/`, and `logout/` built-in views and my custom views and forms are working at those urls. However, the `password_reset/` url continues to display the basic Django admin site webpage for resetting the password, even though I have created the `registration/password_reset_form.html` file. I am at my wits end here as to what is going on - according to all documentation online all that is required to write a custom webpage for the `password_reset/` url is to create the `registration/password_reset_form.html` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[arjun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393607/7953766) answer put me on the right track. The default admin template is called `registration/password_reset_form.html` and this template was overriding my custom template which I had also titled `reigstration/password_reset_form.html`. I solved the problem by changing my custom template's name to `registration/password_reset.html` and setting the `template_name` argument as per [arjun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393607/7953766) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `template_name` argument as well to use your custom template like this.

```
path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html', form_class=CustomPasswordResetForm), name='password_reset'),
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me either - the view still routes me to the basic admin webpage.